# How to tell youtube-comments-task to use the Shadow Socks proxy?

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy

I just started to learn (node) js and want to scrape comments of a list of youtube videos, by adding forEach loop and file output (for every video's comments) into example code provided at https://github.com/philbot9/youtube-comments-task#examples

Following is my code which at least needs SS proxy specification:

```
'use strict';

const fetchComments = require('youtube-comments-task');
const fs= require('fs');

const utbIds = ['eh9OqEd5z1k', 'MPZBVmzAO1M', 'uMnmJlFxxZQ'];

const fetchAllComments = (videoId, pageToken, fetched = []) =>
    fetchComments(videoId, pageToken)
    .chain(({ comments, nextPageToken }) =>
    nextPageToken
    ? fetchAllComments(videoId, nextPageToken, fetched.concat(comments))
    : Task.of(fetched.concat(comments)));

utbIds.forEach(function(utbId) {
    fetchAllComments(utbId)
    .fork(e => console.error('ERROR', e),
    allComments => fs.appendFile(''.concat('comment_',utbId), allComments, (err) => {
        if(err) throw err;
    }));
});
```

This code got 'connection refused' error.

I have to use Shadow Socks proxy through brook GUI client on MacOS.

How to tell youtube-comments-task to use the Shadow Socks proxy?

Any suggestions for correction or improvement to my above code?